# upgrade to playframework 2.1.1 creates json deserialization problems with jeckson. might be connected with akka actor library?

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, akka, playframework-2.1

After I upgraded an application to playframework 2.1.1 I get some deserialization issues in jackson (jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar and jackson-core-asl-1.9.10.jar)

Normal tests executed from play console that serialize to and from json are working ok.
When the same serialization is used inside application it complains like you see in the stacktrace.

I've have the impression that because akka library the classpath somehow is affected.

The code is using two functions

```
public static <T> String toJson(T data) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.warn("can't format a json object from [" + data + "]", e);
        return null;
    }
    //
    // return Json.stringify(Json.toJson(data));
}

public static <T> T fromJson(String description, Class<T> theClass) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode parse = objectMapper.readValue(description, JsonNode.class);
        T fromJson = objectMapper.treeToValue(parse, theClass);
        return fromJson;
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("can't parse a json object of type " + theClass.getName() + " from ["
                + description + "]", e);
        // LOG.warn("can't parse a json object from [" + description + "]", e);
        // return null;
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("can't parse a json object of type " + theClass.getName() + " from ["
                + description + "]", e);
        // LOG.warn("can't parse a json object from [" + description + "]", e);
        // return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("can't parse a json object of type " + theClass.getName() + " from ["
                + description + "]", e);
        // LOG.warn("can't parse a json object from [" + description + "]", e);
        // return null;
    }
}
```

After this I get the following exception in playframework

```
4664956  INFO [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-186] - resync sending states BE-beA ...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type id 'eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.flow.AddSedToFlowControlMessage' (for id type 'Id.class'): no such class found
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:82)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider$WrappedDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializerProvider.java:461)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1286)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:1733)
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.flow.impl.FlowServiceImpl.fromJson(FlowServiceImpl.java:167)
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.flow.impl.FlowServiceImpl.fromBody(FlowServiceImpl.java:144)
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.flow.impl.FlowServiceImpl.resync(FlowServiceImpl.java:130)
        at controllers.Application.renderFlows(Application.java:796)
        at controllers.Application.flows(Application.java:785)
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$22$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(routes_routing.scala:314)
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$22$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(routes_routing.scala:314)
        at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:164)
        at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:345)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:31)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:74)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:73)
        at play.libs.F$Promise$PromiseActor.onReceive(F.java:420)
        at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
4666398  INFO [pool-204-thread-1] - JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01: Stub for http://192.168.1.6:18003/cn/reliableTransport> execute Execute with delay=10 S :java.util.co
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the issue is caused by wrong management of classloader in play-2.1 in dev mode that doesn't configure ReloadableClassLoader (that contains the compiled classes) but SBT/Play shared ClassLoader (which doesn't contain your classes since is the classpath shared by play). The issues is described here http://ben-tech.blogspot.be/2013/05/play-run-in-dev-mode-and.html

The solution was to store the ReloadableClassLoader and configuring it in the current thread class loader:

1. Intercept the ReloadableClassLoader by configuring Global (as described here http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1-RC2/ScalaGlobal **This object must be defined in the default (empty) package.**)

   ```
   //package nopackage;
   // - This object must be defined in the default (empty) package.
   import java.io.*;
   import org.h2.*;
   import com.typesafe.config.*;
   import akka.actor.*;
   import play.*;
   import play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader;
   import play.mvc.*;
   import eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.env.*;
   import eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.utils.*;

   public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
           @Override
           public Configuration onLoadConfig(
                   Configuration config, File path, ClassLoader classloader) {
                   PlayUtils.storeClassLoader(classloader);
                   return super.onLoadConfig(config, path, classloader);
           }
   }
   ```
2. Define PlayUtils

   ```
   //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794298/upgrade-to-playframework-2-1-1-creates-json-deserialization-problems-with-jeckso/16794883#16794883
   public class PlayUtils {
           private static ClassLoader fullClassloader;
       public static void fixClassloader() {
           Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(fullClassloader);
       }

       public static void storeClassLoader(ClassLoader classloader) {
           fullClassloader = classloader;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Call PlayUtils.fixClassloader() in the akka threads before the classes are needed for serialization/deserialization with jackson (or before sql Driver classes of postgresql or h2 are needed). I had problems with these two cases.

   ```
   //in the thread that needs the classloader fix
   PlayUtils.fixClassloader()
   ```

---

Other resources

- https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/822
- http://grokbase.com/t/gg/play-framework/133bamw7n6/play-2-1-0-akka-remoting-classnotfoundexception-after-upgrading-from-2-0-4

Exception listed to help searching

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type id 'eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.bm.CloseFlowChange' (for id type 'Id.class'): no such class found
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:57) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:1.9.10]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:113) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:1.9.10]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:82) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:1.9.10]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:52) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:1.9.10]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider$WrappedDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializerProvider.java:461) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:1.9.10]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:1.9.10]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1286) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:1.9.10]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:1733) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:1.9.10]
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.bm.impl.BusinessMessagingService.fromJson(BusinessMessagingService.java:533) [classes/:na]
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.bm.impl.BusinessMessagingService.fromBody(BusinessMessagingService.java:504) [classes/:na]
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.bm.impl.BusinessMessagingService.resync(BusinessMessagingService.java:459) [classes/:na]
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.bm.client.LocalBusinessMessaging.resync(LocalBusinessMessaging.java:118) [classes/:na]
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.bm.client.LocalInstitutionBusinessMessaging.resync(LocalInstitutionBusinessMessaging.java:100) [classes/:na]
        at controllers.Application.renderFlows(Application.java:639) [classes/:na]
        at controllers.Application.flows(Application.java:917) [classes/:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$30$$anonfun$apply$30.apply(routes_routing.scala:470) [classes/:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$30$$anonfun$apply$30.apply(routes_routing.scala:470) [classes/:na]
        at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:164) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:345) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:31) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:63) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:74) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:73) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.libs.F$Promise$PromiseActor.onReceive(F.java:420) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159) [akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425) [akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386) [akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230) [akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212) [akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502) [akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) [scala-library.jar:na]
SBT/Play shared ClassLoader, with: WrappedArray(file:/c:/apps/play/framework/./sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0/lib/scala-library.jar, file:/c:/apps/play/repository/local/play/play_2.10/2.1.1/jars/play_2.10.jar, file:/c:/apps/play/repository/local/play/sbt-link/2.1
SBT/Play shared ClassLoader, with: WrappedArray(file:/c:/apps/play/framework/./sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0/lib/scala-library.jar, file:/c:/apps/play/repository/local/play/play_2.10/2.1.1/jars/play_2.10.jar, file:/c:/apps/play/repository/local/play/sbt-link/2.1
73424  WARN [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] - Can't deserialize properly [{
  "class" : "eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.bm.CloseFlowChange",
  "created" : "2013-09-25T00:59:03.890+02:00",
  "changeCreator" : {
    "institutionId" : "beA",
    "countryCode" : "BE"
  },
  "changeId" : {
    "value" : "RM.be.20130925T005903.C.22"
```

Classpath issues with jdbc drivers

```
7212 ERROR [New I/O worker #1] - The application couldn't be initialized.
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for j
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:575) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:676) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:720) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.utils.db.PostgresDdlDialect.checkIfExists(PostgresDdlDialect.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
        ...
        at eu.ec.dgempl.eessi.apps.EessiApp.startAllServices(EessiApp.java:324) ~[classes/:na]
        at controllers.Application.createEessiDeployment(Application.java:120) [classes/:na]
        at controllers.Application.configure(Application.java:91) [classes/:na]
        at controllers.Global.onStart(Global.java:27) [classes/:na]
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onStart(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:17) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:175) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:63) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:63) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:63) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:63) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:63) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:62) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:133) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication.get(ApplicationProvider.scala:104) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.Server$class.sendHandler$1(Server.scala:56) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:88) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:87) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:87) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:34) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$6.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:115) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$6.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:115) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:98) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:109) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:108) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.6:5432/postgres
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RE
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource.initConnection(SingleConnectionDataSource.java:244) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource.getConnection(SingleConnectionDataSource.java:186) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 91 common frames omitted
```